# Animate offset().left with hash change jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, hash, offset, hashchange

I'm working on horizontal scrolling website 
Website (blueprint) working very well, animation work smooth and everythings fine.
But when I want to add `window.location.hash` with `ba-hashchange` plugin in this case does not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function(event) {
    window.location.hash =  $(this).attr("href");
    return false;      
});

var newHash      = "";
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash;
    if (newHash) {
        $('body,html').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $(newHash).offset().left
        }, 2500,'easeInOutExpo');
    };

});

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Here's live example without hashChange [WITHOUT HASH EXAMPLE](http://revelier.home.pl/withoutHash/)

And here's with hashChange [WITH HASH EXAMPLE](http://revelier.home.pl/withHash)

Basicly what i want to do:

1. On Click nav new window.location.hash is set
2. plugin with function 'hashchange' read hash
3. and when specific hash animate to direct "id"

What's happening with hash:

1. On Click url changes
2. function "hashchange" does work because when u put alert(newHash) instead animate it shows actual hash, animation just does not work.
3. when u put link with hash changed it works [HASH CHANGED SERVER PATH/#portfolio](http://revelier.home.pl/withHash/#portfolio)

Please help me to combine animation offset with hashchange.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change id to data-id and navigate to not strick id

```
var adres = location.hash.substring(1);


if (newHash) {
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $("div[data-id='" + adres + "']").offset().top,
                scrollLeft: $("div[data-id='" + adres + "']").offset().left
            }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');
}
```

Good luck all :)

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

add a class to all your anchors "**.scroll**"

example: `<a href="#main" class="scroll">Home</a>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var newHash  = "";
        $(".scroll").click(function(event){
        //prevent the default action for the click event
        event.preventDefault();
        var full_url = this.href;
        var parts = full_url.split("#");
        var trgt = parts[1];
        var target_offset = $("#"+trgt).offset();
        var target_top = target_offset.top;
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_top}, 1500,function(){window.location.hash = "#"+trgt;});
     return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: sorry but i dont see how it should work with "hashchange" which i want use give the IE problems. And those code u made says about scrollTop which I dont need. Thx anyway